# Kubernetes (K8S): TCP clients waiting very long timeout on connection to a Service when there are no Pods serving its requests

Tags: tcp, kubernetes, redis

My problem occured when using Redis on Kubernetes, but it seems that it is not a problem with Redis itself, but with network/infrastructure.
My scenario:

- I have a Redis Service with single Redis Pod serving it.
- I connect Redis Client to the Service.
- I delete a Redis Pod.
- Client connection gets ended.
- Redis Client tries to reconnect.
- In this time Redis Replica Ret brings up a new Redis Pod, and the Redis Service starts responding to requests/creating new connections.
- However my existing Redis Client is hanged on connection (first reconnect
  attempt) and it stays that way until it gets timeout (which is
  approximately after **130 seconds**).
- On the second reconnect attepmt it gets connected immediately.

The problem seems to not exists on my dev env (local docker containers), because timeout shows up after a second or 2.

Also, the client that I am using has no option to configure a socket timeout.

1. Is this a proper behavior of a Service - hanging a connection until a timeout occurs whend there are no Pods to handle requests? If it responded with error immediately, there would be no such problem.
2. Is there a way to configure this timeout to acceptable value somewhere (on Service level, on some network configuration, etc.)? Let's say 5 seconds would be ok.

Comment: you need to check a behavior of a new Redis Pod. Try to look through its logs using `kubectl log <pod-name>` command and understand what amount of time is required to start the application

Comment: It's not a pod or redis server problem. New redis pod starts responding in about 10-15 seconds and that's fine. Problem is despite new pod is already responding and k8s service is able to accept new connections, the connections started before there was a new pod are hanged until timeout of 130s ius reached.

Answer (score 0):

A Service is an abstraction in Kubernetes which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them. Technically, a Service is a type of Kubernetes resource that causes a proxy to be configured to forward requests to a set of pods.

In your case, your Redis Client connects directly to your Redis Pod using some firewall rules configured in a Service. Therefore, if the Service was untouched, connection problems may appear only on the Pod side or on the Client side. So, you need to look for configuration settings for them.

Comment: According to these issues on k8s repo, it seems that you are wrong:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47340
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48719
People reported similar problem and from these issues I conclude that it is connected with a service/kube-proxy iptables configuration in Kubernetes.